# Avoiding long-lived references to Activities

Tags: android, android-memory

I have an `Activity`. This `Activity` has a `ListView` with a `BaseAdapter` attached to it. 
In `onDestroy`, the adapter is stored in a class, in `onCreate` it is reattached to the new `Activity`. 
The adapter loads stuff from the internet and creates `Views` for the `ListView`. 
In order to be able to start an `AsyncTask` (to load my data) from the adapter, it needs a `LoaderManager`. I pass it from the `Activity` to the adapter with the `getSupportLoaderManager()` of my `Activity`.

1. Is the following correct: as the adapter is being kept and reattached to `Activities`, it will always hold a reference to the old, long gone `Activity` that I first passed to it, which could / will lead to memory leaks?
2. How can I prevent this? I thought about replacing the adapter's `LoaderManager` every time it is reattached to a new `Activity` with the new `Activity`'s `getSupportLoaderManager()`? 
   Is this safe / common?
3. How can I in general find possibly dangerous references to 'old' `Activities`?

Comment: What does "is stored in a class" mean? Do you mean "is stored in a static data member"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your static data member. Use a retained fragment, or `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, to retain the adapter across configuration changes.

> How can I in general find possibly dangerous references to 'old' Activities?

If by "dangerous" you mean "leaked", [use MAT](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html).

Comment: Wouldn't this still leak as the LoaderManager he is using in the adapter still would have a reference to the destroyed activity after the orientation change?

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineLaFayette: the `Loader` framework is lifecycle-aware, so unless you do something to cause an activity leak, a configuration change should not intrinsically cause such a leak.